# Bootstrap 3 + Phonegap Build 3.3.0 Windows Phone 8 "responsive fix" absolute positioned footer issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, windows-phone-8

I'm building a Phonegap app and had the problem Bootstrap describes [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie10-width) (mostly desktop view instead of narrow "phone" view). Their solution fixed my problem perfectly except introduced a new problem. My footer appears about 20-30px higher than the bottom of the viewport. **This problem only occurs in portrait mode.** Testing on a Lumia 820.

I'm using the following CSS relevant for the footer:

```
height: 45px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

I understood that this is caused by the phone leaving empty space for a navbar/addressbar but it does not make sense to me the issue only occurs with Bootstrap's fix. I tried various suggestions involving setting the device-height but to no avail. Hoping there is someone who ran into this specific issue!

Bootstrap's suggested fix I'm using:

```
@-webkit-viewport   { width: device-width; }
@-moz-viewport      { width: device-width; }
@-ms-viewport       { width: device-width; }
@-o-viewport        { width: device-width; }
@viewport           { width: device-width; }
```

js:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement('style')
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}'))
    document.querySelector('head').appendChild(msViewportStyle)
}
```

Comment: Are you able to inspect the page on the device? It seems maybe there's some margin/padding in the way.

Comment: I tried this with debug.build.phonegap.com and even though it shows some activity it's not loading the element inspector. I've had it working before so perhaps they're currently out of capacity.